# Filter Products based on Product attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create filter like below link

https://paytm.com/shop/g/paytm-home/incredible-offers/smartphones-flat-20-cashback

When i click the smart phone on Landing page then filter show based on smart phone 
Like camera color sim internal memory external memory .. etc

Current i have list of productViewmodel which contain the product and product variant only

Please guide me

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The search term you are looking for is [faceted search](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview).

One option to implementing it is using a faceted search engine, such as [Bobo-Browse.Net](https://github.com/NightOwl888/BoboBrowse.Net) (which is implemented as an extension to the [Lucene.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/) search engine). It is a .NET port of the Java version, meaning it is a 100% .NET solution.

See the [faceted search prototype](https://github.com/NightOwl888/FacetedSearchPrototype) and [car demo](https://github.com/NightOwl888/BoboBrowse.Net/tree/master/src/CarDemo) for some examples of how to implement it in MVC.

> **Full Disclosure:** I am a major contributor to the Bobo-Browse.Net project.

Another option is to use [solr](https://lucidworks.com/blog/faceted-search-with-solr/), which runs as a separate process than the web site that uses it. It is a Java-based solution.

Either way, the best solution from a web site is to use [AJAX](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html) so the drill-down happens without reloading the entire page.

Comment: Thanks for your response , My question is how to based on smart phone how to write Action in controller . Now i return the list of Products selection on Smart phone . Now my question how to get the Brand Name in side of Action related to smart phone and price